Question on Sculpting mode
I was watching Youtube video about the sculpting mode in blender, and I realized in this Youtube video, around 01:28, you can see him drawing tiny lines on the dragon's neck with 6 px of brush radius.
Like this

But when I try it on mine, it just won't happen. I tried with Crease brush on 40 px radius. No matter how big the radius of the brush is, the pixels just keep collapsing like this. I did apply subdivision modifier before going into sculpt mode on the objects just to make them clean and smooth. Could it be the reason why it's not working for me?
I would like to know the correct way to use the sculpting brushes without limits and how.


Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Hello could you please share your file?

Hi, sure. I am new to both this website and blender. Sorry for my mistakes I made on this  post.
Sorry, I can't find a way to share my file here.

You can remove everything that is not relevant from the file and upload it here: https://blend-exchange.com/ (max. 20 MB). Alternatively, you can share a Google Drive link or use a share hoster to share the file if it's too big.
